# How do I git mv files with ext *.css.scss to *.scss using bash?

Tags: bash

I've run into this a few times and I'm curious about automating it. If I want to move a bunch of files matching a pattern to a slightly different pattern, how would I do it?

More specifically, If I want to `git mv` the following files

```
fileA.css.scss
fileB.css.scss
...
```

to

```
fileA.scss
fileA.scss
...
```

How would you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write something like:

```
for file in *.css.scss ; do
    mv "$file" "${file%.css.scss}.scss"
done
```

(Note: I'm not sure of the right arguments for `git mv`, so I just demonstrated using `mv`, I hope that's O.K.)

For information on the `${parameter%word}` notation, see [§3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: Awesome! Can you point me to the docs that explain how bash handles `*.css.scss`?

Comment: @thedeeno: That would be §3.5.8 "Filename Expansion" in the same document.